# How to select a mesh, group or object3d in threejs and higlight it?

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js

I'm new to Three.js and vectors math. I'm trying to build a city-building and economic strategy game. I've been able to add a camera movement using the keys (w,a,s,d), a terrain, trees and a character (from [mixamo.com](https://www.mixamo.com/)).
Now I'm figuring out how to select an existing mesh (or object3D) using the mouse, but I don't understand quite well how could I achieve this. I guess, on the onclick function I have to create a vector where the mouse position is or somehow. As I said I'm new to vectors maths and still don't understand quite well. I'm doing this in plain js (no framework or whatever).

**EDIT ------**

Thanks to Martin's comment I've been able to advance. My `MouseControllerInput` now looks like this:

```
export default class MouseControllerInput {
  constructor() {
    this.#_init();
    this._raycaster = new Raycaster();
    this._pointer = new Vector2();
    this._active = false;
  }
  get pointer() {
    return this._pointer;
  }
  get raycaster() {
    return this._raycaster;
  }
  get active() {
    return this._active;
  }
  #_init() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.#_onClick());
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.#_onClick());
  }
  #_onClick() {
    return (v) => {
      this._active = !this._active;
      this._pointer.x = (v.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      this._pointer.y = -(v.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    };
  }
}
```

And the mouse controller looks like this:

```
import MouseControllerInput from "./input.js";

export default class MouseController {
  constructor(SceneEntity, CameraEntity) {
    this._scene = SceneEntity;
    this._camera = CameraEntity;
    this._input = new MouseControllerInput();
  }
  Update() {
    if (this._input.active) {
      this._input.raycaster.setFromCamera(this._input.pointer, this._camera);
      const intersects = this._input.raycaster.intersectObject(this._scene);

      console.log(intersects);
      for (let i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
        // Don't select if object's parent is the terrain
        if (intersects[i].object.parent.name === "terrain") continue;

        function hihlightTree(tree) {
          tree.children.forEach((c) => {
            if (c.children.length > 0) {
              c.children.forEach((c2) => c2.material.color.set(0xff0000));
            } else {
              c.material.color.set(0xff0000);
            }
          });
        }

        // Change color if intersected objects are tree's childs
        if (intersects[i].object.parent.name === "branches") {
          if (intersects[i].object.parent.parent.name === "tree") {
            let tree = intersects[i].object.parent.parent;
            hihlightTree(tree);
          }
        } else if (intersects[i].object.parent.name === "tree") {
          let tree = intersects[i].object.parent;
          hihlightTree(tree);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm able to select trees. But my question now is how to make the object's material color be the initial (brown and tree) when selected again.

[repo](https://github.com/Jaime-Alvarez-Lopez/threejs_introduction)

Comment: What you are looking for is called raycasting and there is a comprehensive example for that here: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=raycast#webgl_interactive_cubes

Comment: @MartinSchuhfuß thanks for the comment. See update if you can help me more.

Comment: you mean, return it to the original color when deselected? For that, you can store the original color somewhere (for example in object.userData like this: `c.userData.origColor = c.material.color.clone(); c.material.color.set(highlightColor);`)